# pacman -Syyu syncs removed package

Tags: sublime-text-3, pacman

I recently switched from sublime-text-3 to vim and wanted to uninstall the former. I used `pacman -Rsnc sublime-text` and it worked just fine.

But whenever i do `pacman -Syyu` i still see

```
 core                            134.6 KiB   251K/s 00:01 [##############################] 100%

 extra                          1656.5 KiB   293K/s 00:06 [##############################] 100%

 community                         4.8 MiB  47.8K/s 01:44 [##############################] 100%

 sublime-text                   1827.0   B  0.00B/s 00:00 [##############################] 100%

 sublime-text.sig                543.0   B  0.00B/s 00:00 [##############################] 100%
```

I tried deleting these 2 last files from `/var/lib/pacman/sync` but they are regenerated each time `pacman -Syyu` is used.

It does not cause any problems as far as I can tell but i find it annoying. Anyone having a clue on how to remove them would be great.

Comment: What is in your /etc/pacman.conf?  Have you added sublime-text as repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a package. That's a *repository*, just like [core] and [extra] are repositories. It is configured in `/etc/pacman.conf` – remove the entire section that starts with `[sublime-text]`.